# How to change value for jquery-ace code editor text area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have an ACE code editor on my webpage that is supposed to refresh with a new value as the drop down option is changed. Currently, when the function is called via 'onchange' of the drop down, an alert message appears. However, I'm unable to change what is displayed in the ACE code editor.

I am using this jQuery plugin - http://cheef.github.io/jquery-ace/. It doesn't have much documentation.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="column-left">
 <h2>Sources</h2>
    <%= collection_select(:source, :select_source, Source.all, :id, :name, options = {include_blank: "Please select a source..."}, html_options = {:onchange => "updateTextArea()"}) %>
 </div>
 <div class="column-center">
 <h2>Code</h2>
  <textarea id="txtbox1" class="my-code-area" rows="20" style="width: 100%">awaiting source...</textarea>
 </div>
</div>


<script>
    $('.my-code-area').ace({
        theme: 'twilight',
        lang: 'ruby'
    })
    var decorator = $('.my-code-area').data('ace');
    var aceInstance = decorator.ace;

    function updateTextArea() {
        var text = "source changed"
        alert(text);
        aceInstance.edit("txtbox1").setValue("source changed");
    }    
</script>
```

Comment: try replace setValue() to value()

Comment: That didn't help. It actually seems that "edit" itself is problematic - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'edit' of undefined. So I might be mistaken to assume that aceInstance is equivalent to var editor = ace.edit("editor"); (https://ace.c9.io/#nav=embedding)

Comment: create sample in sandbox plz

Comment: Where are you calling `updateTextArea()` from?

Comment: calling it from the onchange action of the collection_select. included that bit of code too now in question.

Comment: i find way to add text to editor but not change...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get ace instance from jquery wrapper using

```
var editor = $('.my-code-area').data('ace').editor.ace
```

and then call

```
editor.setValue("text")
```

or if you want to reset the undo manager

```
editor.session.setValue("text")
```

Comment: The editor.session.setValue("text") is a better fix than creating and destroying the ace instance each time. Also, it addresses the issue of not appending to the string of what already exists in the code editor each time the updateTextArea function is called.

Answer (score 0):

I found way to change value...

```
$('.my-code-area').ace({
    theme: 'twilight',
    lang: 'ruby'
    });

    function updateTextArea() {
    var decorator = $('.my-code-area').data('ace');
    var aceInstance = decorator;
    var text = "source changed"
    aceInstance.destroy();
    aceInstance.create();
    aceInstance.editor.theme('twilight');
    aceInstance.editor.lang('ruby');
    aceInstance.editor.value('source changed');
    }
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you! Basically, the ace code editor instance must be destroyed and re-created with change in drop down.